# how to reset password for customers

Tags: smtp

i am new on Magento 2 i have a new magento 2 instance , i want to check the reset password functionality in my website , when i enter the email they said to men the email was sent to the email that I filled ,but i didn't receive anything, i think because i haven't configure the smtp yet.

> can anyone help me please to configure and send the email to the customers for resetting their passwords ?

what they said to me :

```
If there is an account associated with careca@gmail.com you will receive an email with a link to reset your password.
```

Comment: you need to smtp configuration in your store

Comment: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp